# Etiquette: How many reminders should one send for conference speakers to submit their talk info?

Tags: conference, etiquette, email, communication

I am co-organizing a conference that will take place virtually on Mar 13, 2023. We invited the speakers and they confirmed their participation in Nov, 2022. Now, we sent them a form that collects their talk info + bios + photos, and a consent form to sign in Jan. and some of them have not submitted their info yet nor emailed us the signed consent form until now.

We sent a reminder on Feb 2 and they have not submitted the data yet! - I know that professors are busy but also this is putting a lot of stress on us, "the organizers", the registration for the event ends on Mar 9!

It is a volunteer conference so we offer no honorarium to the speakers and maybe that is why they are not taking it seriously but we (the organizers) are taking our volunteering work seriously and we care about the details!

I am uncomfortable asking them again to submit their info. What advice do you have for me?

Those who are late on submission are old professors and probably busy, and I am a graduate student.

And also, how to write an effective but gentle reminder email to the professors who are late on submission?

Here is what I came up with:

> Hello all,
>
> Hope this email finds you well. We are very excited that (conference
> name) is approaching and we cannot wait to meet you all!
>
> Could you please fill out these forms and email us the consent form if
> you have not done so at your earliest convenience ideally before the
> end of Feb? - Registration closes Mar 9.
>
> Thank you.
>
> BR, xxx

Comment: You didn't really give a deadline.

Comment: I am trying to tell them that the deadline is Feb 28 in a polite way. I am uncomfortable telling them the deadline is Feb 28.

Comment: "Ideally" is just a suggestion, not a deadline. Be Bold.

Comment: What is the relation between them providing this info and registration closing?

Comment: Why do they need to consent to talking?

Comment: I bet it is a photo release or similar!

Comment: @TimRias So that people registering can decide if they're interested

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- For most people, simply the list of invited speakers should be enough to do that.

Comment: "Hello all,

Hope this email finds you well. We are very excited that (conference name) is approaching and we cannot wait to meet you all!" Consider that such impersonal, generic headers are awfully close to the conference spam a researcher will be getting regularly. Having an attachment (for the forms) could strike even more red flags for spam.

Comment: As someone who took part in organising an international conference as an undergrad student and was responsible for sending out e-mails to participants and speakers, I can report that not a single recipient took any kind of umbrage to receiving ‘strong’ messages from a mere student. Most presumably didn’t know I was just a student – they just saw an e-mail from a conference organiser. Repeated reminders of specific deadlines (polite, of course) were appreciated across the board.

Comment: Being polite and being firm aren't mutually exclusive.  Change your text to **"Please fill out and email us the consent form, if you have not done so already, no later than 28 Feb.  Otherwise, we will assume that you are not able to serve in a speaking capacity, and look forward to your registration as an *attendee* no later than 9 Mar.  Thank you for helping us make this a great conference, and we look forward to hearing from you."**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As many reminders as it takes to get the information! I would keep a few things in mind. Decide on a firm deadline. Put it in the subject line. “Deadline 2/28: Submit program info for Name of Conference” Then send this to each person by name. When the email goes to many people (“Dear All”), it seems that many people are late. If I get a personal note, I get the impression that everyone else has submitted. Good luck.

Comment: I put something like [Action required] at the start of the subject. And +1 for personal emails, not 'dear all'.

Comment: If it’s an international conference, I’d avoid writing “Deadline 2/28” – non-Americans are likely to read that as ‘deadline 2 of 28’. Better to avoid ambiguity and write, “Deadline 28 Feb[ruary]” (or “28th Feb[ruary]” or whichever style of writing it out you prefer).

Answer (score 11):

Send one more and give a deadline (firm). "If we don't have your material by -firm date- you won't appear in the program."

If the recipients don't see the consequences of being later then there is little incentive (from their standpoint) to be "ideal". Make it clear.

Comment: I agree with providing a firm deadline, but the wording ("you won't appear in the program") seems a bit too strong (even if true), given that the speakers are volunteering their time and effort.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, how about "can't appear"? The volunteers can't just make stuff up.

Comment: There's some tuning, I'd be partial to: "We need your material by end of day Feb 28 to prepare the program, after which speakers whose information we're missing won't appear in the program." But that's all small quibbling, the most important part is to put a firm deadline. Also, **bold** it in the email.

Answer (score 10):

The way busy people read email is often a triage system. People make a quick decision on whether the email requires a response immediately, requires a response later, or doesn't require a response. For busy people with a lot of emails, the "requires a response later" category can quickly slide into "never going to get around to it."

So your strategy should be to make it extremely clear that your email *does* require a response immediately. Don't worry about being overly polite -- often including additional extraneous words beyond your request simply makes it harder for the person to determine what you need, which makes them more likely to decide that the email is not something they need to respond to right away. Just state what you need simply firmly and make it clear there is time pressure. Furthermore, personalizing emails adds pressure to respond.

> Dear Prof X,
>
> We are excited for your upcoming talk at the Y conference.
>
> The deadline for title/abstract/bio submission is Z. Please make sure to submit your material by the deadline so that we can include your information on the website.
>
> Thank you,
>
> Nadine

Comment: +1  "often including additional extraneous words beyond your request simply makes it harder for the person to determine what you need,"

Answer (score 4):

It seems you think it is rude to tell them about a deadline. What is ten times ruder is not telling them about the deadline, they miss it, and as a result can't speak on the conference.

So tell them. Using words that are hard to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest being more direct. Explain it as your problem (like the printer of the program being a stickler for a deadline). But make very clear what you need doing and by when. Otherwise many will not even realise the need. If you want additional background put that after the call to action.